# No arXiv id showing in bibtex generated by Mendeley

Tags: bibtex, arxiv

I noticed that those arXiv papers in my bibliography are not correctly showing their arXiv id. Is there any fix to this?

Thanks

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: I was using 'ieeetr' simply because it gives me citation order, authors, article title and journal. Arxiv id won't appear. I don't really care about the style as long as those attributes are present

Comment: You could try the bib style `hiiietr.bst`, available at http://arxiv.org/hypertex/bibstyles/.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do as Mico suggests, and download a style that supports formatting the arXiv ID in the output. Then, you need to add some fields to the BibTeX entry. The key fields are the `eprint`, `archivePrefix` and `primaryClass` fields, where `eprint` contains the arXiv ID number, `archivePrefix` contains the archive (`arXiv` for the arXiv), and `primaryClass` contains the arXiv class of the document. Then, you need to download a style file, such as the `utphys` style available at http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/~distler/TeXstuff/utphys.bst. That file takes care of formatting the arXiv ID as well as the DOI (if present), so that with this MWE, you get the appropriate output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{Braun:2014dca,
      author         = "Braun, Harald and Schmidt, Wolfram and Niemeyer, Jens C.
                        and Almgren, Ann S.",
      title          = "{Large-eddy simulations of isolated disc galaxies with
                        thermal and turbulent feedback}",
      journal        = "Mon.Not.Roy.Astron.Soc.",
      number         = "4",
      volume         = "442",
      pages          = "3407-3426",
      doi            = "10.1093/mnras/stu1119",
      year           = "2014",
      eprint         = "1405.6245",
      archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
      primaryClass   = "astro-ph.GA",
      SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = ARXIV:1405.6245;%%",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Test text~\nocite{*}
\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{utphys}
\end{document}
```

[image]