# Mendeley and arxiv citation style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, arxiv

I'm using Mendeley as article-library. How can I format the citations as follows ?

[image: blabla]

In particular I would like the Arxiv-link to be displayed...

PS: I already saw a previous similar question [No arXiv id showing in bibtex generated by Mendeley](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173044/no-arxiv-id-showing-in-bibtex-generated-by-mendeley)
However Mendeley asks a CSL document for importing a new style, but arxiv only provides a bst-document.... (Whatever these two styles might be.)

Comment: Good question! You're confusing a little bit the process of how LaTeX will get the data from Mendeley. Mendeley exports a BibTeX (`.bib`) file that contains all the citation information, even stuff that won't get used in the final format. LaTeX (actually, BibTeX, the program) uses a style file (`.bst`) to determine how to format the citations in your document. The Citation Style Language (`.csl`) file required by Mendeley is used for the Mendeley integration with Word and LibreOffice. So you actually need to 1) make sure that the export from Mendeley (`.bib`) includes the arxiv field...

Comment: ...and 2) make sure that the `.bst` file you use adds the arxiv ID to the format. You can use the link Mico posted on the question you linked to to help find an appropriate `.bst`

Comment: CSL refers to the Citation Style language (xml based), it defines styles for every kind of  bibliography http://citationstyles.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to collect a few pieces of information for your document. The first is to make sure that you have enabled showing the arXiv ID for documents. This should be on by default (I think), but if not, you can follow this question to enable it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180216/32374

Then, export whatever documents you want (or perhaps the whole library) to a `.bib` file. You can set this up automatically in the options, or you can select a particular article, right click and choose "Export" (or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>). Save the file **WITHOUT SPACES IN THE NAME** in the same folder as your TeX document.

Then, download the `utphys.bst` from http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/~distler/TeXstuff/utphys.bst, and save that in the same folder as your TeX file as well. Now, when you set up your bibliography at the end of your document, simply set the `\bibliographystyle{utphys}`, and the arXiv ID should be produced in the output. If you load the `hyperref` or `bookmark` packages in your preamble, there will even be links to the appropriate places. Be aware that if you use that particular `.bst` file, you'll get duplicated `arXiv:arXiv:ID` in your output. Simply delete the `arXiv:` in the `eprint` field of your `.bib` file to fix it.

Don't worry about the `filecontents` environment in the following example, that's just what I'm using instead of the direct output from Mendeley. Just delete that environment and substitute `the-name-of-your-bib-file` for `test` in `\bibliography{the-name-of-your-bib-file}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{Braun2014,
abstract = {We present a subgrid-scale model for the Multi-phase Interstellar medium, Star formation, and Turbulence (MIST) and explore its behavior in high-resolution large-eddy simulations of isolated disk galaxies. MIST follows the evolution of a clumpy cold and a diffuse warm component of the gas within a volume element which exchange mass and energy via various cooling, heating and mixing processes. The star formation rate is dynamically computed from the state of the gas in the cold phase. An important feature of MIST is the treatment of unresolved turbulence in the two phases and its interaction with star formation and feedback by supernovae. This makes MIST a particularly suitable model for the interstellar medium in galaxy simulations. We carried out a suite of simulations varying fundamental parameters of our feedback implementation. Several observational properties of galactic star formation are reproduced in our simulations, such as an average star formation efficiency \~{}1\%, a typical velocity dispersion around \~{}10 km/s in star-forming regions, and an almost linear relationship between the column densities of star formation and dense molecular gas.},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
arxivId = {arXiv:1405.6245v1},
author = {Braun, H. and Schmidt, W. and Niemeyer, J. C. and Almgren, A. S.},
doi = {10.1093/mnras/stu1119},
%eprint = {arXiv:1405.6245v1},%This is the original line from Mendley
eprint = {1405.6245v1},%This is the corrected line
issn = {13652966},
journal = {Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society},
keywords = {Formation - galaxies,Ism,Numerical - stars,Turbulence -methods},
number = {4},
pages = {3407--3426},
title = {{Large-eddy simulations of isolated disc galaxies with thermal and turbulent feedback}},
volume = {442},
year = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Test text~\nocite{*}
\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{utphys}
\end{document}
```

[image]